# How to control how many xlabels are printed in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot, axis-labels

I'm working on a heatmap style of displaying daily activity using Gnuplot's colorbox with a matrix of data:
[image]

A sample part of the data file:

```
Week commencing,29 Jun 2020,06 Jul 2020,13 Jul 2020,20 Jul 2020,27 Jul 2020,03 Aug 2020,10 Aug 2020,17 Aug 2020,24 Aug 2020,31 Aug 2020,07 Sep 2020,14 Sep 2020,21 Sep 2020,28 Sep 2020,05 Oct 2020,12 Oct 2020,19 Oct 2020,26 Oct 2020,02 Nov 2020,09 Nov 2020
Mon,11,6,0,4,4,9,10,7,5,0,22,10,9,8,9,2,4,11,11,7
Tues,3,5,0,6,3,4,11,3,6,12,6,3,4,4,9,12,2,1,8,2
Weds,10,1,0,9,4,1,6,5,6,3,2,5,1,5,7,5,8,10,2,12
Thurs,6,3,0,8,3,2,7,14,10,12,14,8,1,3,19,11,8,16,3,7
Fri,16,1,2,5,10,3,0,1,10,1,13,10,0,10,6,10,7,4,9,5
Sat,6,6,8,21,2,7,0,11,0,7,2,23,2,8,11,11,5,3,12,0
Sun,8,7,3,1,8,2,8,2,2,2,6,6,3,3,2,2,4,5,8,0
```

With this script:

```
DATAFILE="done_tasks_matrix.csv"
set term png size 800, 300 font "Avenir,9"
set datafile separator comma columnheaders
set palette rgbformula -9,2,-9
set cbrange [0:*]
set cblabel "Completed tasks (Goals + Projects + Other)"
unset cbtics
set xrange writeback
set yrange [6.5:-0.5] writeback # to get it displaying Mon->Sun not Sun->Mon down the page
set xdata time
set timefmt "%d %b %Y" # format of the dates in the input
set format x "%d %b" # format of dates to show
set output "/Users/jonathan/Dropbox/NPSummaries/done_tasks_heatmap.png"
plot DATAFILE matrix rowheaders columnheaders using 1:2:3 with image, \
     DATAFILE matrix rowheaders columnheaders using 1:2:($3 == 0 ? "" : sprintf("%g",$3) ) with labels font ",8" tc rgb "#22BB22"
```

As I gather more data the xlabels are overlapping. I can't find a way to have it show only *1 in n* labels. However, on simpler line graphs with dates as the xlabel Gnuplot seems to drop labels automatically to make sure they don't overlap.

Is it possible to drop some of the xlabels, or do I need to alter the input data so that some are blank?

Bonus question: why does the output include the second plot line as text, as well as obeying its instructions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Tom Solid already pointed out, the easiest is probably to just rotate the xtic labels.
Your "bonus question" can also be answered with inserting a line: `unset key`.

By the way `set xdata time`, `set timefmt "%d %b %Y"`, etc. in your code has no effect. The columnheaders will just be used as text for the xtic labels.

A different (and bit more complex) suggestion would be to convert the dates into calendar weeks. This will save space. But keep in mind there are different definitions when the week starts (Sun or Mon?) and what calendar week 1 is.

**Code:**

```
### schedule with calendar weeks
reset session

$Data <<EOD
Week commencing,29 Jun 2020,06 Jul 2020,13 Jul 2020,20 Jul 2020,27 Jul 2020,03 Aug 2020,10 Aug 2020,17 Aug 2020,24 Aug 2020,31 Aug 2020,07 Sep 2020,14 Sep 2020,21 Sep 2020,28 Sep 2020,05 Oct 2020,12 Oct 2020,19 Oct 2020,26 Oct 2020,02 Nov 2020,09 Nov 2020
Mon,11,6,0,4,4,9,10,7,5,0,22,10,9,8,9,2,4,11,11,7
Tue,3,5,0,6,3,4,11,3,6,12,6,3,4,4,9,12,2,1,8,2
Wed,10,1,0,9,4,1,6,5,6,3,2,5,1,5,7,5,8,10,2,12
Thu,6,3,0,8,3,2,7,14,10,12,14,8,1,3,19,11,8,16,3,7
Fri,16,1,2,5,10,3,0,1,10,1,13,10,0,10,6,10,7,4,9,5
Sat,6,6,8,21,2,7,0,11,0,7,2,23,2,8,11,11,5,3,12,0
Sun,8,7,3,1,8,2,8,2,2,2,6,6,3,3,2,2,4,5,8,0
EOD

set datafile separator comma
unset key

set palette rgbformula -9,2,-9
set cbrange [0:*]
set cblabel "Completed tasks (Goals + Projects + Other)"
unset cbtics
set style fill solid 1.0

set locale "English_US"    # if not already set, to correctly interpret the month abbreviations
set xlabel "Calendar week"

myCW(col) = sprintf("%s",strftime("%W",strptime("%d %b %Y",strcol(col))))  # date --> calendar week
stats [*:*][*:*] $Data u 2 skip 1 nooutput  # get the number of columns
MaxCol = STATS_columns
set xrange [-0.5:MaxCol-1.5] 
set yrange [6.5:-0.5]

plot $Data matrix rowheaders using 1:2:3 skip 1 with image, \
     $Data matrix rowheaders using 1:2:($3==0 ? "" : sprintf("%g",$3) ) skip 1 with labels font ",8" tc rgb "#22BB22", \
     for [i=2:MaxCol] $Data u (i-2):(NaN):xtic(myCW(i)) every ::0::0 
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:**

@JGC, that's the advantage of gnuplot, somehow there will be a solution, sometimes a bit cumbersome but mostly some workaround exists.

Typically, I consider data as a given and fixed. In some cases you might have the possibility to change the data format already while creating it and adapt it to gnuplot's "special needs" to achieve your special wishes.

As I mentioned, your labels are too long. `plot ... matrix columnheaders` will just use them all as text labels. I'm not aware that you can directly skip a few. But this is gnuplot, ... so, there is a workaround.

1. you need to know how many columns you have. This, you can find out using `stats`. However, gnuplot doesn't recognize columns if the first line are headers or strings, that's why you have to skip the first line, i.e. `skip 1`. Although there is the syntax `plot for [i=2:*] u 1:(column(i)) ...` which should loop all columns, I experienced that this can lead to gnuplot hanging or crashing (I haven't found out yet why this is and how to reproduce it regularly).
2. with the following construct you can select how many of the xtic labels you want to have shown: `for [i=2+Noffset:MaxCol:Nxtic] $Data u (i-2):(NaN):xtic(strcol(i)) every ::0::0`. Here: every `Nxtic=4` label with an offset of `Noffset=1`. Furthermore, I would consider it important to have some xtic marks visible, especially if your xtic label is rather long. Otherwise you wouldn't know which column the date actually belongs to.

**Code:**

```
### schedule from matrix with every nth label only
reset session

$Data <<EOD
Week commencing,29 Jun 2020,06 Jul 2020,13 Jul 2020,20 Jul 2020,27 Jul 2020,03 Aug 2020,10 Aug 2020,17 Aug 2020,24 Aug 2020,31 Aug 2020,07 Sep 2020,14 Sep 2020,21 Sep 2020,28 Sep 2020,05 Oct 2020,12 Oct 2020,19 Oct 2020,26 Oct 2020,02 Nov 2020,09 Nov 2020
Mon,11,6,0,4,4,9,10,7,5,0,22,10,9,8,9,2,4,11,11,7
Tue,3,5,0,6,3,4,11,3,6,12,6,3,4,4,9,12,2,1,8,2
Wed,10,1,0,9,4,1,6,5,6,3,2,5,1,5,7,5,8,10,2,12
Thu,6,3,0,8,3,2,7,14,10,12,14,8,1,3,19,11,8,16,3,7
Fri,16,1,2,5,10,3,0,1,10,1,13,10,0,10,6,10,7,4,9,5
Sat,6,6,8,21,2,7,0,11,0,7,2,23,2,8,11,11,5,3,12,0
Sun,8,7,3,1,8,2,8,2,2,2,6,6,3,3,2,2,4,5,8,0
EOD

set datafile separator comma
unset key
set palette rgbformula -9,2,-9
set cbrange [0:*]
set cblabel "Completed tasks (Goals + Projects + Other)"
unset cbtics
set style fill solid 1.0
stats [*:*][*:*] $Data u 2 skip 1 nooutput    # get the number of columns
MaxCol = STATS_columns
Nxtic = 4
Noffset = 1
set xtics out
set yrange [6.5:-0.5]

plot $Data matrix rowheaders using 1:2:3 skip 1 with image, \
     $Data matrix rowheaders using 1:2:($3==0 ? "" : sprintf("%g",$3) ) skip 1 with labels font ",8" tc rgb "#22BB22", \
     for [i=2+Noffset:MaxCol:Nxtic] $Data u (i-2):(NaN):xtic(i) every ::0::0
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @theozh, for the suggestion. As it happens I don't want to use calendar weeks as they don't trigger associations in the same way that months do. And given enough data they will also crash into each other. Which is why I'm after an automatically-adapting solution.

Comment: Also thanks @tehozh for clarifying for me about xdata vs column headers.

Comment: @JGC, see addition with the flexibility of showing only every Nth label.

Comment: Excellent @theozh -- that's what I'm after.

Answer (score 2):

#### Main Question

I can't find the simple way to "drop some of the xlabels" with some options. As you said, if you can "alter the input data so that some are blank” easily like the following, it is a shortcut to getting the output you want.

```
# Week commencing,29 Jun 2020,06 Jul 2020,13 Jul 2020,20 Jul 2020,27 Jul 2020,03 Aug 2020,10 Aug 2020,17 Aug 2020,24 Aug 2020,31 Aug 2020,07 Sep 2020,14 Sep 2020,21 Sep 2020,28 Sep 2020,05 Oct 2020,12 Oct 2020,19 Oct 2020,26 Oct 2020,02 Nov 2020,09 Nov 2020
Week commencing,29 Jun,,,20 Jul,,,10 Aug,,,31 Aug,,,21 Sep,,,12 Oct,,,02 Nov,
Mon,11,6,0,4,4,9,10,7,5,0,22,10,9,8,9,2,4,11,11,7
Tues,3,5,0,6,3,4,11,3,6,12,6,3,4,4,9,12,2,1,8,2
Weds,10,1,0,9,4,1,6,5,6,3,2,5,1,5,7,5,8,10,2,12
Thurs,6,3,0,8,3,2,7,14,10,12,14,8,1,3,19,11,8,16,3,7
Fri,16,1,2,5,10,3,0,1,10,1,13,10,0,10,6,10,7,4,9,5
Sat,6,6,8,21,2,7,0,11,0,7,2,23,2,8,11,11,5,3,12,0
Sun,8,7,3,1,8,2,8,2,2,2,6,6,3,3,2,2,4,5,8,0
```

The first line is a comment out of the original line. The second line
is inserted to store the labels to be displayed at xtics. If you have such an input file, you can simply run your script and get the image like this.

[image]

#### Bonus(?) Question

You can also remove long strings in legends by doing the following,

```
set key noautotitle
```

"set key autotitle" is the default setting. And no title string is explicitly given in the plot command (including the keyword "notitle"), the string of the plot command itself will be displayed in the legend as you can see. The command above disables this default setting.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can rotate the `xtics`

```
 set xtics rotate by -90
```

Bonus: put `notitle` after your second plot:

```
plot DATAFILE matrix rowheaders columnheaders using 1:2:3 with image, \
     DATAFILE matrix rowheaders columnheaders using 1:2:($3 == 0 ? "" : sprintf("%g",$3) ) with labels font ",8" tc rgb "#22BB22" notitle
```

Comment: Thanks @Tom Solid, that's fixed the unwanted text. Any idea why it treats it as a title? Or is this a bug?

Comment: I'm also still after an answer to the main question; rotating the label is possible, but isn't as elegant as what I have in mind.

Comment: @JGC: no, this is not a bug. For every ploted datasets and curves, there will be a key; the default is the ploting command itself. You can set the keys of the curves/datasets by `t` or `title` or you can unset them with `notitle`. Or, as @theozh has mentioned, you can unset all keys, by `unset key`.
By the way, your first plot also has an unwanted key, but it is just covered by the second plot.

Comment: Thanks for explaining what's going on with the defaults of keys/titles @Tom Solid. I get it now!